# C# Windows Services Counter

Tags: c#, windows-services

Really stuck with trying to get windows services to count through to ten seconds (accurately) and print each time it loops through to a text file.
I've read a number of entries that `Timer` is not the way to go, however I'm very new to C# and cannot figure out how else you would go about this.

I am unsure how to fetch the counter timer (if it works) to only run through six or so times and how to output this to the text file specified within OnStart.

EDIT: there will be next to no CPU available for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Current code shown below, the debug bit is so I can test it without having to install.

```
public partial class CountDown : ServiceBase
{
    public bool RunMyTimer = true;
    public int DelayMyTimer = 10000; // ten seconds
    private int TimerControl = 0;

    public TrapModule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // debugging to check whether OnStart works
    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // begin service  + putting a file 
        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // stop service
    }
    //Time Keeping
    public class Timer1
    {
        public long counter = 0;
        public System.Threading.Timer stopWatch = null;
        public bool enabled = false;
    }
    private void Reset(object state)
    {
        Timer1 ts = (Timer1)state;
        long timerCount = ts.counter;
        if (ts.counter >= Int64.MaxValue - 1)
        {
            ts.counter = 0;
            ts.counter = ts.counter + 1;
        }
        if (RunMyTimer)
        {

            ts.stopWatch.Change(TimerControl, DelayMyTimer);
        }
        else
        {
            ts.stopWatch.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

Comment: Is your intention to start a process that recurs every ten seconds? Or is it a process that runs for ten seconds, at 1 second intervals? Either way you can probably do what you want with a while loop and a thread.sleep(n milliseconds). This way, each iteration of the loop will wait 1000 or 10000 milliseconds before going to the next iteration. It all depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: A process that runs through every 10 seconds (exact), 6 times for this example and outputting 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the text file stated in the OnStart.

Comment: `while RunMyTimer {
/*do stuff, output to file*/
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayMyTimer);
}`

Is probably a pretty good choice. Is millisecond accuracy good enough? Make sure to put that in your OnStart

Comment: Apologies @Eric - there will almost no CPU usage allowed for this as it'll be going on a server (I've now altered my question to reflect this. Which would put a while loop out of the running I think.

Comment: a while loop will not execute as long as the Sleep method is used. The loop will not use up any CPU while "waiting" for thread to finish sleeping. Of course, when I say "not any CPU" i mean nothing of any consequence, everything uses some CPU.

Comment: No, but this will be progressive bit of code and more will be added to it. Reading various amounts of data from servers every so often. So if all of that's in a while loop it'll cause complications and I would be back to where I am now unfortunately, usually that would solve this issue, but not in this case sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows services, you have to start some kind of thread in the `OnStart` method in order for the service to keep running.  If you don't do this, the service will start and immediately quit once it's installed and executed from the Services console.  Fortunately, you're wanting to run a timer, which can satisfy this condition.

Below is some code I've written and tested to achieve what I understand you to be asking for.

```
public partial class CountDown : ServiceBase
{
    public CountDown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _fs = System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _fs.Close();
        _timer.Close();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = String.Format("{0} - Count #{1}\n", DateTime.Now, _counter++);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        _fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private System.IO.FileStream _fs;
    private int _counter;
}
```

Note that timing on Windows systems is not accurate.  In the example, I've specified 1000 milliseconds as the timer interval, but this will not guarantee that the `Elapsed` callback will be executed **precisely** every second.  It'll be close, but not on the nose.

Here's the example output from my OnStart.txt file:

```
8/5/2014 10:59:26 AM - Count #0
8/5/2014 10:59:27 AM - Count #1
8/5/2014 10:59:28 AM - Count #2
8/5/2014 10:59:29 AM - Count #3
8/5/2014 10:59:30 AM - Count #4
8/5/2014 10:59:32 AM - Count #5
8/5/2014 10:59:33 AM - Count #6
8/5/2014 10:59:34 AM - Count #7
8/5/2014 10:59:35 AM - Count #8
8/5/2014 10:59:36 AM - Count #9
8/5/2014 10:59:37 AM - Count #10
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that - how can I ensure best possible outcome for seconds, as close to the nose as possible?

Comment: By specifying 1000 milliseconds, you're saying run this every second.  However, the Windows OS will execute it with up to 15-18 milliseconds of error in our experience.  So you need to assess how close to one second it needs to be.  Is one second +/- 15-18 milliseconds good enough?  My guess is yes.  If not, you could perhaps play around with some of the high-performance timers, but these supposedly drift over time.  GL